# Does Flyway Community version support Oracle 19.7?

Tags: flyway

Does flyway community version support Oracle 19c? From this URL: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle, it is up to 19.3. My oracle database is 19.7. I am not very familiar with oracle database versions.

Any version support oracle 19.7 at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no breaking changes have appeared in Oracle 19.7, then yes, we just have not formally tested it yet. If you try, you will get a warning to this effect in the log but Flyway will function as normal. I'll update the tests and remove this warning for the next patch version.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you know when the next patch will happen?

Comment: They're approximately weekly.

Comment: Having said that... Oracle haven't made the right binaries available for us just yet. Are you using an on-premise db, or a cloud service?